# Python build Error : Failed to build these modules: _ssl

Tags: python, ssl, build

I want to install python 2.7.13 in my working OS. The OS is following:

> Linux XXX-centos-01 2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 21 19:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I download python source and compile with the following step:

> Step1
>
> > ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib/python2.7.13 --enable-ipv6
>
> Step2
>
> > make

No Error but fail to build __ssl :

> Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
>
> _tkinter           bsddb185           dl
> imageop            sunaudiodev
>
> To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
>
> Failed to build these modules:
>
> _ssl

But the openssl module i have installed.

> [root@lhkvm77-centos-01 Python-2.7.13]# rpm -aq|grep openssl
>
> openssl-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64
>
> openssl-devel-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64

so i am confused for it. Please help to fix it.

Comment: Does `yum search python` show any python2.7 package? If yes, run `yum install packagename`.

Comment: yes, but these are only some plugin/third party for python, when i try "yum install python", it shows "Package python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 already installed and latest version"

Comment: Finally, i download a lower version of python 2.7.5 source code from offical website and build, the problem of fail build module _ssl disapper.